# How can I profile Arbortext Editor (Epic) Java plugin?

Tags: java, plugins, intellij-idea, profiler

I use IntelliJ IDEA. I need to profile plugin for Arbortext Editor (Epic). It launches my plugin which consists of a set of *.class files. Arbortext Editor has internal JRE 1.42 folder.I am able to debug the plugin using commands like `set javadebugport=3500;` in the special acl script file. The plugin cannot be run directly within IDEA. Instead of it I launch epic.exe and choose Debug in the IDE. The IDE knows about `javadebugport` value.
Here is acl contents (the 2nd string belongs to YourKit Java Profiler setting):

```
 set javadebugport=3500;
 set javavmargs= -agentpath:"D:\\YourKit\\bin\\win32\\yjpagent.dll"
 java_console();
```

`set javavmargs= vmargs`
explanation:

> The value of this option will be passed to the Java Virtual Machine
>   (JVM) as command line arguments when the JVM is loaded. This option
>   can't specify the class path. Set the class path using the set
>   javaclasspath option.

But profiling in YourKit does not work.Anvir Task manager shows that yjpagent.dll is not loaded.
`javavmargs` is transformed by Arbortext Editor into corresponding Java arguments. 
Is it possible to profile this plugin within IDEA or without it using one of the profilers: YourKit Java Profiler, JProfiler, visualvm_134?

Comment: So, I need a profiler for 1.42 Java plugin.

Comment: So, I need a profiler for 1.42 Java plugin. – ilya 4 hours ago 
I am able to use 1.5 Java too, but for Epic 5.2.